# How to find out which interface a method was called on?

Tags: java

I have a simple Java question. Consider the following interfaces:

```
interface A { 
    void work();
    void a();
}

interface B {
    void work();
    void b();
}
```

So when a class is going to implement them, it should be like this:

```
class Impl implements A, B {
    void work() {
        /*some business*/
    }

    void a() {}
    void b() {}
}
```

My question is, in `work` method, how would I find out that, it has invoked by type `A` or `B`?

The above class in C# would be like this, and this separates both implementations very well:

```
class Impl : A, B
{
    void B::work() {}
    void A::work() {}
    void a() {}
    void b() {}
}
```

But how would I achieve something like C# model in Java?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Neither. The idea of an `interface` is that a class that implements it, agrees with the "contract" the interface implies. If you have two interfaces, requiring both to implement a method `work()`, and a class that implements both interfaces, then it has to implement `work()` to agree with the contract of both.

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) says:

> Implementing an interface allows a class to become more formal about
>   the behavior it promises to provide. Interfaces form a contract
>   between the class and the outside world, and this contract is enforced
>   at build time by the compiler. **If your class claims to implement an
>   interface, all methods defined by that interface must appear in its
>   source code before the class will successfully compile.**

And that is exactly what you do by implementing a `work()` method: you satisfy both interfaces `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 3):

Your interface only tells you the signatures of the methods that the implementing class needs to provide. In your example both `A` and `B` ask for a method `work()` that has `void` as return type. So basically they are both asking for the same method. I don't see how you could or would need to differentiate?

Answer (score 3):

You might have a problem with diamand implementation.
You need to specified it by your own.

```
void work() { A.super.work(); } // or B.super.work();
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `work` will satisfy the requirements of both interfaces.  The method is contained on the class, which can instantiate both interfaces.  In order to implement the interface the class must possess the methods specified in the interface.  It does not matter if the same method is used to satisfy the requirements of multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

JVM will not be invoking A or B, but only the implementation Impl. You can cast back to A or B and your client can invoke methods based on the methods available in the specific interface.

Comment: This is not quite right. It might or might not be invoking an interface method, depending on how the method is called.

Comment: If you can not instantiate anything, you can not invoke. Interface methods are invoked (but on implementation only). Interface only defines the compliance that implementation classes implements. I guess we both are trying to say the same, but in different ways.